# How can I use a directive wrapper for ng-grid with the grid options determined by a directive attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to create a re-usable directive wrapper for [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) where I can apply the location of the ng-grid options through the use of an attribute.

Here is the skeleton of the code which gets *very* close to what I want:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('grid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="someObject.gridOptions"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
             // no code here necessary, to use the hard-coded ng-grid options
        }
    }
}]);
```

What I would like to do is supply the variable for ng-grid by using an attribute, similar to this:

```
<grid dataLocation="someObject.gridOptions"></grid>
```

I've tried using the compile and the link options with multiple methods, including reading the attributes, and then using the `element.html()` method to update the html to set the ng-grid attribute to "someObject.gridOptions", as well as using `{{someScopeVariable}}`, and setting `scope.someScopeVariable` to "someObject.gridOptions" in the linking function. I have verified using the chrome's html inspector that the div's attribute looks correct, but I have not been able to get the item to show up on my page.

I suspect I'm running into issues since the ng-grid is already a compiled directive. Is there any way I can pull this off? I've tried a large number of compile and linking methods with no success yet.

Comment: Do you have a JS Fiddle where we can see this?  My guess is that you need to add the isolate scope '=' so that your directive can talk to the nested directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the original template's attributes, the `template` option of `directive` should be defined as a function as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('grid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function(element, attrs){
            return '<div ng-grid="' + attrs.dataLocation + '"></div>';
        }
    };
});
```

Your HTML stays the same:
`<grid dataLocation="someObject.gridOptions"></grid>`

Comment: Ah! Of course. I missed the fact that template could accept a callback. I found a different way around my problem, but I see no reason why this would not have worked as well.